# Drupal 8 REST PATCH on multiple nodes

Tags: json, rest, curl, drupal, patch

I am trying to create multiple nodes PATCH for a content type. Currently I am able to patch one node only:

```
curl --include \
--request PATCH --user username:password \
--header 'Content-type: application/hal+json' \
--header 'X-CSRF-Token: <obtained from http://my_website.com/rest/session/token>' \
http://my_website.com/node/1862?format=hal_json \
--data-binary '{"_links":{"type":{"href":"http://my_website/rest/type/node/faq"}},"title":[{"value":"Example node title UPDATED!"}],"type":[{"target_id":"faq"}]}'
```

I would like to update all 'faq' content type nodes from other GET which I can generate on http://my_other_website_which_is_my_source.com/api/rest/all_faq_nodes

Is it possible to add the GET result to --data-binary?
I was trying to get more info on Drupal sites with no luck unfortunately.

Drupal version: 8.2.1

Cheers!

Comment: Note that PATCH is per definition not RESTful

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. I ended up creating a rest plugin to handle multiple nodes (create or update).

First, use drupal console to generate a custom rest resource plugin. My examples uses POST verb.

**%>drupal generate:Plugin:rest:resource**

Then, in @RestResource section, add/update the following annotations:

**serialization_class = ""**

**https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/api/multinodespost**

Since the serialization_class is not specified, you can pass an array of nodes in json format such as:

[image]

The data passed to the post function will be of normalized form instead of serialization class type; so, you will end up with normalized data in two-dimensional array (see *Symfony Serialization componen*t for detail).

public function post($data) { ... }

You can iterate through the elements of $data (two-dimensional array) and convert each element (normalized data) to a Drupal Entity\Node using denormalize() function.

You can visit my [blog](http://jphandson.blogspot.com/2016/12/drupal-8-create-rest-plugin-to-allow.html?view=classic) for detail. I hope this helps.